# Is there a way to find a Teamviewer ID in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program which logs user activity, and I'd like to be able to get a Teamviewer ID and send it to a log, I know how to send the information to the log by assigning that information to a variable, however I'm not sure how to pass a teamviewer ID to said variable and would like some help on this.

Any and all help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Apparently these are outdated but a good place to start, `VBSCRIPT` - http://www.sole.dk/vbscript-to-show-current-teamviewer-id-and-save-to-text-file/ 
`C#` - http://hintdesk.com/how-to-get-id-and-pass-of-teamviewer-programatically/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, However I've seen these links while doing research on this issue, I'm a beginner in c# and was hoping for a clearer explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For TeamViewer 8 in Windows 8 the TeamViewer ID is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version8\ClientID

From here on it is simply a matter of reading that registry key in C# and then do whatever you want with it, if need be I'll provide code for registry reading :) But http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C explains it really well already! Best of luck!

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! Fantastic answer thankyou very much :D

Comment: Have a look at my answer as well, there are other registry locations you will want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38267908/5369260

Answer (score 12):

### Edit 2024-04-03

Method updated to work also with TeamViewer ver. 15.

---

Version 10 has a bit different position in Registry.

The following code works with ver. 10 and also older versions. It also takes differences between 32 bit and 64 bit OS into account:

```
public static string GetTeamViewerId() {
    try {
        string[] regPath = { @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer", @"SOFTWARE\TeamViewer" }; // newer versions
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regPath[0]);
        if (key == null)
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regPath[1]);
        if (key == null)
            return "0";
        object clientId = key.GetValue("ClientID");
        if (clientId != null) //ver. 10
            return clientId.ToStringIgnoreCulture();
        foreach (string subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames().Reverse()) //older versions
        {
            RegistryKey openSubKey = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);
            if (openSubKey != null)
                clientId = openSubKey.GetValue("ClientID");
            if (clientId != null)
                return clientId.ToStringIgnoreCulture();
        }
        return "0";
    } catch {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Registry keys are disposable so should be within a using statement

Comment: I think my method doesn't leak. But generally speaking, yes, IDisposable objects should be handled properly.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I'm using.

```
    public static string GetTeamviewerID()
    {
        var versions = new[] {"4", "5", "5.1", "6", "7", "8"}.Reverse().ToList(); //Reverse to get ClientID of newer version if possible

        foreach (var path in new[]{"SOFTWARE\\TeamViewer","SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\TeamViewer"})
        {
            if (Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path) != null)
            {
                foreach (var version in versions)
                {
                    var subKey = string.Format("{0}\\Version{1}", path, version);
                    if (Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey) != null)
                    {
                        var clientID = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("ClientID");
                        if (clientID != null) //found it?
                        {
                            return Convert.ToInt32(clientID).ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Not found, return an empty string
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Registry keys are disposable so should be within a using statement

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution might be correct in some cases, however the ClientID can be located in other locations in the Registry.

1. It depends on whether or not you are using a 64-bits OS. On 64-bits OS you need to include \Wow6432\.
2. Sometimes the registry location ends with a version (for example \Version9), but I have seen cases where it doesn't.

Possible locations:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version[version]
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version[version]
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string TvId()
{
    return Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\TeamViewer\\Version6", "ClientID", "FAILED").ToString();
}
```

Comment: This answer might be more concise, but it will fail in so many cases, it's not a good solution. See answer from Igor Gorjanc or Devsoft for instance.

Comment: Well, it is short, and it leaves the programmer the responsibility of the correct version path.

Comment: Fair enough, for some specific use cases, it might still be helpful.